# Fast algorithm for finding all solutions of simple equation involving only addition of terms from list

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra, coefficients

I have a list $X=\{n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4, \dots, n_i\}$ with $n_i \in \mathbb{C}$, an integer $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $S \in \mathbb{C}$. My question is how to find all solution to the equation

$$\sum_{j=1}^m x_j=S
$$
in an efficient way with Mathematica?

---

An example:

```
X={1,1/2,0,-1/2,-1};
m=3;
S=1;
```

I want a function `combinations[X,m,S]` which returns

```
combinations[X,m,S]
{{1,3,3},{3,1,3},{3,3,1},{1,2,4},{1,4,2},{2,1,4},{4,1,2},{2,4,1},{4,2,1},{1,1,5},{1,5,1},{5,1,1},{2,2,3},{2,3,2},{3,2,2}}
```

where each triple gives the index to `X`.
For example, `{1,3,3}` stands for

$$S=x_1+x_3+x_3=1+0+0=1.$$

---

The solution I have is very slow and takes a lot of memory: I perform m tensor-products of $X$, creating a $M=i \otimes i \otimes \dots \otimes i$ matrix (with dimension of $d(M)=i^m$, and sum each entry. Unfortunatly, the matrix M grows exponentially, and is unfeasible even for small $m$ below 20.

So let me two ask:

> 1) Do you know a more efficient solution for finding all solutions of the equation above?
>
> 2) Do you know a more efficient solution for finding all solutions of the equation above, for the special cases of $S=0$ and $S=1$?

Comment: This isn't exactly the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution), but dynamic programming seems like the answer.

Comment: `IntegerPartitions[S, {m}, X]` and post-process (`Permutations`)?

Comment: @kglr wow I was trying `IntegerPartitions` before and couldnt get it work, i didnt know about the third argument. It works for rational numbers, that is already really cool, thanks! Could this be extended to complex values? (at least for question 2?) Thaanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For rational $n_i$ and $S$, you can use `IntegerPartitions`:

```
X = {1, 1/2, 0, -1/2, -1};
m = 3;
S = 1;

posIndex=PositionIndex[X];

Flatten /@ Map[posIndex, Join @@ (Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[S, {m}, X]), {-1}]
```

> {{5, 1, 1}, {1, 5, 1}, {1, 1, 5}, {4, 2, 1}, {4, 1, 2}, {2, 4, 1}, {2,1, 4}, {1, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 3}, {1, 3, 3}, {3, 
>         2, 2}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 2, 3}}

Comment: Very beautiful application of `IntegerPartitions`. As complex numbers can be interpreted as 2dimensional real numbers, would it be possible to modify your code to also cover complex rational `X` and `S`? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @NicoDean. For complex `X` and `S` with rational real and imaginary parts, I think we can use `MapThread[IntegerPartitions[#, {m},#2]& , {ReIm @ S,Transpose[ReIm @ X]}]` to get the core part. Of course, because we are using `Permutations`   `m`  has to be small.

Comment: I think I understand what you try to do with `ReIm`. I tried now for some time but unfortunatly I cannot get it running. So in case that it is clear for you how to continue from there, could you maybe give some more hints? Otherwise i will try further myself. Thanks

Comment: @NicoDean, sorry --- we need to change `Transpose[ReIm @ X]` to `se[ReIm/ @ X]` (or better to `ReIm@X`).

Answer (score 5):

Could use `Solve`.

The example in question:

```
xvals = {1, 1/2, 0, -1/2, -1};
m = 3;
ss = 1;
```

Set up the equations and inequalities that need to be enforced.

```
vars = Array[n, Length[xvals]];
constraints = 
  Flatten[{Total[vars] - m == 0, vars.xvals - ss == 0, 
    Thread[vars >= 0]}];
Solve[constraints, vars, Integers]

(* Out[221]= {{n[1] -> 0, n[2] -> 2, n[3] -> 1, n[4] -> 0, 
  n[5] -> 0}, {n[1] -> 1, n[2] -> 0, n[3] -> 2, n[4] -> 0, 
  n[5] -> 0}, {n[1] -> 1, n[2] -> 1, n[3] -> 0, n[4] -> 1, 
  n[5] -> 0}, {n[1] -> 2, n[2] -> 0, n[3] -> 0, n[4] -> 0, n[5] -> 1}} *)
```