# Combinatorics with booleans equations

Tags: algorithm, boolean-computation

I have variables $X_i \in \{1,0,-1\}$. Now I add up $m=3$ variables

$$S=X_1 + X_2 + X_3
$$

and want to find all combinations that give me, $S=1$. I can do this with (see [this solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202495/fast-algorithm-for-finding-all-solutions-of-simple-equation-involving-only-addit)):

```
m=3;
Xi={1,0,-1};
IntPartition = IntegerPartitions[1, {m}, Xi] (* decomposition of S=1 into m=3 terms from Xi*)
ValueArray = Join @@ (Permutations /@ IntPartition) (* get all combinations *)
posIndex = PositionIndex[Xi];
IdxArray = Flatten /@ Map[posIndex, ValueArray, {-1}] (* get the indices from Xi *)
(* IntPartition={{-1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}
ValueArray={{-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}
IdxArray={{3, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}} *)
```

I want a translation of this to boolean equations. For each of the variables `X1, X2, X3`, i use three bits to encode the corresponding numerical value (using [One-Hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot)). For example:

```
X1w1=False; (* not +1 *)
X1w2=False; (* not 0 *)
X1w3=True; (* -1 *)
```

means that `X1` has the value of `-1`.

**The goal now:** I want to find all $S=1$ as a boolean equation.

My solution creates for each possible combination, seen in `IdxArray`, a logical term. For example, `IdxArray[[1]]={3, 1, 1}` means:

```
Logic1=(!X1w1&&!X1w2&&X1w3)&&(X2w1&&!X2w2&&!X2w3)&&(X3w1&&!X3w2&&!X3w3)
```

This is only the first out of six possibilities of `S=1`. The whole equation looks like this:

```
FullLogic=((!X1w1&&!X1w2&&X1w3)&&(X2w1&&!X2w2&&!X2w3)&&(X3w1&&!X3w2&&!X3w3))||((X1w1&&!X1w2&&!X1w3)&&(!X2w1&&!X2w2&&X2w3)&&(X3w1&&!X3w2&&!X3w3))||((X1w1&&!X1w2&&!X1w3)&&(X2w1&&!X2w2&&!X2w3)&&(!X3w1&&!X3w2&&X3w3))||((!X1w1&&X1w2&&!X1w3)&&(!X2w1&&X2w2&&!X2w3)&&(X3w1&&!X3w2&&!X3w3))||((!X1w1&&X1w2&&!X1w3)&&(X2w1&&!X2w2&&!X2w3)&&(!X3w1&&X3w2&&!X3w3))||((X1w1&&!X1w2&&!X1w3)&&(!X2w1&&X2w2&&!X2w3)&&(!X3w1&&X3w2&&!X3w3))
```

This equation is obviously huge, and the **big problem** comes if one has $m>3$, for example $m=10$, there are 5 elements in `IntPartition`, but the permutation leads to 8350 elements in `ValueArray`. This leads to enormous logical equations.

> **Question**: How can I check with a boolean equation that $S=1$ when I add $m$ variables in a (much) more efficient way than presented above?
>
> Could I somehow exploit `IntPartition` directly instead of creating all of its permutation (`ValueArray`)?

I see no way forward at the moment, and this would be very important for a particular project. Any hint (also to papers) would be highly apprechiated!

Comment: You have 3x the terms necessary in FullLogic. It's possible to check the validity of the one-hot encoding with `BooleanCountingFunction` once, and then in the main body of FullLogic you can write `x1w1` instead of `(x1w1 && !x2w2 && !x3w3)`.